# Service Console errors in javascript console

Tags: javascript, servicecloud, opencti, custom-service-console

one of our customers is getting some errors in their DevTools Console after using the Service Console for certain period of time and I believe those errors are causing the DOM to break and cause issues in other applications that are integrated in this case a Softphone app.

In the first image I see 2 relevant errors one in ConsoleMasterWindow.js and the second one in aura.prod.js

In the second image right there where it says ENTERING INCOMING CALL and then there is an issue with the Knowledge component which is part of their Service Cloud implementation right after that theres a CANCEL log specifying that the call was terminated.

All errors are coming from Salesforce libraries and none from our libraries, any thoughts?

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: Sounds like those are SFDC bugs ?Is it affecting you by any means ?

Comment: The 500 error from salesforce may have been a transient error. [NA30](https://status.salesforce.com/status/NA30) did not report an outage, but then again, maybe they caught it and fixed it already. You might also contact your telephony provider (CloudCaller.io) just to make sure it's not a bug in their code, either. If refreshing the page fixes the errors, it may also be a session time out, so you might check your org's session settings. Alternatively, you might need to contact support directly, since there's *nothing* we can do to fix problems like this.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I'm the developer for CloudCaller.io, this error is happening to one of our customers, so far we filed a ticket with Salesforce, but haven't received a good response, I'm thinking the same that a time out is happening since this issue is resolved by refreshing the page